# jQuery beginner - accordion menu, but jittery buttons

Tags: jquery, menu, expandable

I built an accordion FAQ menu as part of a personal exercise [here](http://jsfiddle.net/freqn/P5SgY/62/)

There's a slight jitter/shake when clicking the buttons that I can't seem to solve for. I've searched Google, but to no avail for something that works. Any ideas?

Also, is there a more efficient way to write the code? Here's what I have:

```
(function () {

    $('dd').hide();
    $('dt').click(function(){
        $(this)
            .next()
            .slideDown(100)
            .siblings('dd')
            .slideUp(100);
    });

    $('dd').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

})();
```

Comment: No jitter for me..what browser?

Comment: Google Chrome - both Mac and PC versions

Comment: I'm on chrome and no problems..

Comment: I just checked and see it in Safari too. It's very subtle and not a huge issue, just a slight bother that I was hoping to find a workaround for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but could it be that you're seeing the sub-pixel renderer adjusting the inter-colour border in response to elements on the page moving around?

Unfortunately, if this is the case, there's little you can do about it from a web application.  At best, you can pick a colour scheme with less button border contrast, which would make the wobble less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the jquery custom theme that you are currently using?

Comment: this really belongs in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Doing animations with jQuery is actually quite expensive in terms of performance. I would suggest not using animations that is likely your problem.

Also, you could also use jquery ui as they have solved the accordion problem already. No sense in re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling some transition effects to get your desired result. Use CSS3 where possible; or stick with jQuery if you'd rather.

```
$(this).animate({
    'paddingBottom': 5,
}, 300, 'linear')
```